# How to resolve alias in tsconfig.app.json for multiple source directories in WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, webstorm, tsconfig

I generate some of our source files outside of the `src` directory.
The structure is:

```
- project
  - generated
    - $ui-services
        some-other.service.ts
  - src
    - app
      - $ui-services
          some.service.ts
```

In tsconfig.app.json I specified:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "paths": {
    ...
    "@ui-services/*": ["app/$ui-services/*", "../generated/$ui-services/*"],
    ...
  }
},
"include": [
  "./**/*.ts",
  "../generated/**/*.ts"
]
```

In SomeOtherService now I can import SomeService like this:

```
import {SomeService} from '@ui-services/some.service';
```

It's working like expected, but now I lost any WebStorm development support in some-other-service.ts. WebStorm seems not to be able to resolve the alias correctly.

I already tried to mark both folders as Resource Root as some have suggested but that didn't help.

Is there anything I can do to fix the resolution to files in the other directory?

Comment: WebStorm does support path mappings, so it should be able to resolve your aliases. What webStorm version do you use? Can you share a sample app that shows up the issue?

Comment: @lena: it is 2018.1 from March 22, 2018. I can try to create a sample app, how can I share this with you?

Comment: 2018.1 should support `tsconfig.app.json` files (https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/02/webstorm-2018-1-eap-181-3741/)... you can put a project on some file server, or push it to github, and provide a link

Comment: Here is a sample project: https://github.com/westor21/webstorm-aliases-example - As I note, in that example I have support for class members. But at least I see an error for the import: TS2307: Cannot find module '@ui-services/some-other-service.service'

Comment: @lena: I updated the project. Now you can see missing support for the class member in the "generated" folder (function is inherited from the base class in the "src" folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will face the same issue when running `tsc` in command line. Typescript compiler uses the nearest `tsconfig.*.json` current file is included in, scanning folders from the file dir up to the project root. The nearest configuration file for `generated/$ui-services/some-service.service.ts` is the `tsconfig.json` file located in the project root, and this config doesn't have any aliases defined, thus tsc reports `TS2307` errors, and members can't be resolved.
Copying path mappings to the root config should solve the issue:

```
"paths": {
      "@ui-services/*": ["src/app/$ui-services/*", "generated/$ui-services/*"]
    },
```

Comment: The compile error was another problem of a missing dependency - I didn't test enought befor submitting the last change. In the sample project is everything working now, independend of where the path declaration ist.
I compared everything of this sample project with my "real" project, I cannot find any difference, but the real problem still brings the problems in webstorm.
And the "real" project compiles. But webstorm cannot resolve the paths, independend in which json file I drop them.
Do you have any idea, what else I could check?

Comment: this doesn't work with your sample project as well - for the reason I explained in my answer. To verify this, try the following: close all editor tabs, close the project. Re-open the project, then open `generated/$ui-services/some-service.service.ts` - you will see compiler errors in it.

Comment: You won't see errors if you open `app.component.ts` or `app.module,ts` first - they import `some-service.service.ts`, and this file will be compiled using `tsconfig.app.json` when compiling these files, so error won't be shown. But if you open  `generated/$ui-services/some-service.service.ts` first, the nearest `tsconfig.json` (root one) will be used, mappings won't be resolved and you will see errors. You have to either move mappings to the root file, or create a separate config with mappings in the `generated` folder

Comment: Thank you, that did it. :-) I just had to ajust the paths for the tsconfig.json .